# Purpose of '@' in Unix Date command (for epoch)

Tags: command-line

Can anyone explain what the significant of the '@' symbol in the following command

```
date -d @1472067906.1413 +%Y.%m.%d
2016.08.25
```

How does the date command handle this; I can't seem to find any information on man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best hint in the man page is indeed in one of the examples – `@x` means x seconds past the epoch:

> EXAMPLES
>
> ```
>    Convert seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) to a date
>
>           $ date --date='@2147483647'
> ```

(I assume there could otherwise be parsing ambiguities if you wanted something like 7 seconds past the epoch: `date --date=7` thinks you want 7AM of the current day.)